# I would like to have a searchable journal (calendar) of my completed tasks in trello

Tags: trello

I would like to use a simple kanban board to track what should I do. But obviously, the "Done" list will be larger and larger (I can archive, instead to move to Done list). Another problem, that I would like to see the completed tasks in a calendar, so I can see, that what did I do last Friday. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

A Google Account with an [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/wtf) recipe can help you achieve this.

---

***Prerequisites***

1. Google Account

   - If you don't use Gmail, you can sign up for a Google Account using your [existing (non-Gmail) email address](https://accounts.google.com/signupwithoutgmail?hl=en).
   - Once you have a Google Account, you will have access to Google Calendar among other apps.
2. IFTTT Account

   - Sign up for IFTTT if you don't have an account already.
   - Navigate to the `Channels` section and link your Trello and Google Calendar to IFTTT.

[image: Add IFTTT Channels]

---

***Setup***

3. IFTTT Recipe

   - Create a [recipe](https://ifttt.com/recipes/299812-track-new-cards-on-google-calendar) to track cards added to your `Done` list in Trello on Google Calendar.
   - Every time you move a card to `Done`, IFTTT will create the card as an event on your Google Calendar.

[image: Create IFTTT recipe]

---

***Caveats***

- The IFTTT recipe uses Gooogle Calendar's 'Quick Add' feature. So, all the information shows up in the title of the calendar event. You'll want to factor that in if you go with this approach.

---

***Bonus***

If this setup works for you, consider setting up [another IFTTT recipe](https://ifttt.com/connect/google_calendar/google_drive) that adds a new row to a Google Sheet you specify.

Comment: Thanks, honestly that was the idea that came to my mind, but hoped that something inside trello exists. It has a calendar feature.

Comment: As for the caleandar quick add thing: is it still true, that I cannot add an event to a specific calendar? If yes, I will go with the google sheet version

Comment: @pihentagy Ah, I understand. Inside Trello it's a bit tricky. Your cards have to have a due date before they show up in the calendar view. However browsing and searching for your 'Done' events in Google Calendar is not bad. To my knowledge, IFTTT only connects to your main Google Calendar. You can't point it to a specific calendar.

Answer (score 0):

To have an overview of **accomplished** cards in Trello:

1. When done, move a card to a list named like **Done on day/week/month X**
2. At the end of day/week/month X move the list to another board named "Report on things done in 2015" or anything like that.
3. On that board switch to the calendar view (free power-up) and see all the cards done by date in Trello.

Notes:

- moving to another board helps to keep the active board clean and fast;
- you won't have a detailed view like checklists done, only cards;
- you won't see daily activity (liking moving cards, making comments, etc), which is quite a different aspect anyway; instead you get only cards 100% completed fair and square;
- you'll have either get things done in time at due dates :-) or adjust due dates to the date when they were really done right before moving to the report board.